# jquery marquee with Next Previous and Stop Pause / Resume Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, plugins, marquee

I'm have download jQuery plugin to display marquee from the following link .

http://www.givainc.com/labs/marquee_jquery_plugin.htm     (jquery.marquee.js)

Now I Need to Add Next Previous and Pause button.

I have done with Pause / Resume functionality but not able to achieve Next Previous.
As following is my code which I have implemented

```
if (options.PPS) {
            $("#btnPause").click(
            function() {
                // if hard paused, prevent hover events                
                if (paused) {
                    resume();
                }
                else {
                    // pause scrolling
                    pause();
                }
            });

            $("#btnRightLeft").click(
            this.next = function() {
                       showNext();
            });
        }
```

Or if any other such jquery / JavaScript Plugins.

Comment: What do you mean by next and prev? are you looking for a jQuery carousel plugin?

Comment: Move Next / Previous Record (move to next <UL>)

Answer (score 0):

Have found following Plugin.

[www.jquerynewsticker.com](http://www.jquerynewsticker.com/)

But its Limitation is that it do not support long text (will only show text which can be fix in display area rest of the text will not be displayed )